# Toggle With Vue in ASP.NET Core Application

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I'm making an ASP.Net Core web app and in it I have a checkbox toggle that has some Bootstrap 4 styling and is hooked up to Vue using v-on:change:

```
<input v-on:change="changeCurrency()" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="SEK" data-off="EUR" data-onstyle="light" data-size="sm">
```

However, the v-on:change method doesn't fire if the element is decorated with:

```
data-toggle="toggle"
```

Does anyone know any other way of perhaps making a similar toggle and having it work with Vue? I looked into perhaps creating a Vue toggle, but didn't find much information on how to implement that into an ASP.NET Core application.

Comment: Just trying to understand this, what do you need `data-toggle` for?

Comment: It's for styling

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap's Javascript package as well? It might be hijacking the listener away from Vue

Comment: Have you considered using [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/)?

Comment: I didn't even know that existed - I will check it out, thanks!